# How to reach a variable that is in a function from another function?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I reach the variable "count_down", from the other function called "STOP" so I can "clearInterval(count_down)".

> Code

```
    function START(){
        let count_down = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        up.setAttribute("disabled" , true)
        down.setAttribute("disabled" , true)
        count.innerHTML = "stop";
        return count_down;
    }


    function STOP(){
        clearInterval(count_down)
        up.removeAttribute("disabled");
        down.removeAttribute("disabled");
        count.innerHTML = "start";
    }
```

> Troubleshoot:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: count_down is not defined
    at STOP (main.js:112)
    at HTMLButtonElement.count.onclick (main.js:123)
```

Comment: You can declare it globally and use it

Comment: Better create a interval class with member as countdown and methods as start and stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
let count_down=0;

function START(){
        count_down = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        up.setAttribute("disabled" , true)
        down.setAttribute("disabled" , true)
        count.innerHTML = "stop";
        return count_down;
    }


    function STOP(){
        clearInterval(count_down)
        up.removeAttribute("disabled");
        down.removeAttribute("disabled");
        count.innerHTML = "start";
    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, no idea how I didn't solve this myself. Thanks. Have a good day!